# Open side drawer from custom button exist in a container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to open side drawer from a button exist in a container not from the AppBar side button. Also this should be open from right to left. 
For more information I have added screenshot of my requirement [image: er]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have a basic sample:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      endDrawer: Drawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("open drawer"),
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Or you can use `GlobalKey` of `ScaffoldState`:

```
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      endDrawer: Drawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("open drawer"),
          onPressed: () {
            _key.currentState.openEndDrawer();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check this link for more information : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/openEndDrawer.html

Answer (score 1):

create a scaffold key then give it your scaffold widget

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

then, to open drawer

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer()
```

or

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer()
```